# How can I select every second pair of elements with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Can you use jQuery to select elements 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15 and so on? That is, select two elements, leave two, select the next two, leave two, etc.

Comment: if you can express it with a formular, like 2n+1 for all odd numbers, then yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combining css nth-child selector and union you can get what you want.
Assuming that you are selecting some div:

```
$('div:nth-child(4n+2), div:nth-child(4n+3)')
```

Comment: man, how could I not come to select every second and every third element separately ) Thx!

Answer (score 2):

*If* you are talking about an array you can do this in pure JS (assume you are selecting from `elements`).

```
var elements = getElementsByTagName(""); //For example
for (var i = 2; i < elements.length - 1; i = i + 4) {
    myArray.push(elements[i]);
    myArray.push(elements[i+1]);
}
```

Comment: Not jQuery but close enough ^^

To actually create the array you can use regular js (like getElementsByClassName() OR jquery('.THECLASS')

Comment: Indeed, but why would you use jQuery here? Given that jQuery decomposes into pure JS I don't see the point in passing through the library for something so simple. And he still hasn't specified if he wants to cycle through page elements or simple array values...

Comment: I need to cycle through page elements, sorry.